Azure Synapse time out - Token expire
Backstory: I have 12 zip files in Gen2 storage, each around 300 mb.
I am running a notebook within a pipeline job.
It goes smoothly until extracting the 6th zip file using pd.read_csv(compression ='zip').
around the 27min 57 secs mark, the token is expired.
So I open and played the synapse notebook.
ClientAuthenticationError: Server failed to authenticate the request. Please refer to the information in the www-authenticate header.
ErrorCode:InvalidAuthenticationInfo
Authenticationerrordetail: Lifetime validation failed. The token is expired.
When I run a pipeline, it dies down at the similar position.
I am using the bare minimum as my company doesn't have enough funds for increasing nodes, etc.. Microsoft suggest to apply a retry-upon-failure. Also said synapse inability to handle token refreshes for non-users identities.
Is there a work around for this? Or is there screencaps that can assist me? Thanks!

Can you try  split the workload into smaller, sequential jobs

How you are authenticating. using linked service credential?

In synapse you have below option to authenticate.
Using linked service and Using storage options.

Create a linked service to adls gen 2 account and use it while reading the files.


You can use system or user managed identity for authentication.
code:
import pandas as pd
   
df = pd.read_csv('abfs://<container_name>@<storage_acc_name>.dfs.core.windows.net/<path>/parse1_data_preview.csv', storage_options = {'linked_service' : '<linked_service_name>'})
df

Output:

This doesn't expire, linked service handles the things.

In storage option below, you can pass below credentials.

code:
   import pandas
   
   #read data file
   df = pandas.read_csv('abfs://file_system_name@account_name.dfs.core.windows.net/   file_path', storage_options = {'account_key' : 'account_key_value'})
 
   ## or storage_options = {'sas_token' : 'sas_token_value'}
   ## or storage_options = {'connection_string' : 'connection_string_value'}
   ## or storage_options = {'tenant_id': 'tenant_id_value', 'client_id' : 'client_id_value',    'client_secret': 'client_secret_value'}

Here, i recommend to use tenant_id, client_id, and client_secret.
Refer below documentation for more information.
Tutorial: Use Pandas to read/write ADLS data in serverless Apache Spark pool in Synapse Analytics - Azure Synapse Analytics | Microsoft Learn
Tutorial: Use FSSPEC to read/write ADLS data in serverless Apache Spark pool in Synapse Analytics - Azure Synapse Analytics | Microsoft Learn
If you still want to use the tokens you need to keep on checking the expiry.
Below is the logic, you alter it according to your requirement.
token_expiry_buffer = 300 
token_expiry_time = 0

def get_token():
    global token_expiry_time
    token = credential.get_token("https://storage.azure.com/")
    token_expiry_time = token.expires_on
    return token

def is_token_expired():
    current_time = time.time()
    return current_time >= (token_expiry_time - token_expiry_buffer)
    
paths = ["zip1path","zip2path","zip3path"...]

for path in paths:
    if is_token_expired:
    #refresh the token
        get_token()
    df = pd.read_csv("path")


After applying your suggestion with a little extra, there is no more token timeout, but another issue rose at the 54 min 32 sec mark:  "Session failed. Run the notebook to start a new session." & "InvalidHttpRequestToLivy: Submission failed due to error content =["requirement failed: Session isn't active."] HTTP status code: 400." mssparkutils.fs.mount("abfss://xx01@zz.dfs.core.windows.net", "/mount1", {"linkedService": "linkedserviceac01"}) and pd.read_csv(f'file:{mssparkutils.fs.getMountPath("/mount1")}{path_to_the_file}{zip_file}' , compression ='zip', sep='|' )

You increase the session timeout in right the side session configuration, also your session should be active else it will be automatically goes to inactive state.
